# Ubuntu 18.04.1 no longer detects 2560x1440 on external display

Tags: display, display-resolution

So it appears Ubuntu is no longer recognising my monitor (AOC q2790pqu) as a  QHD monitor and won't allow a resolution higher than 1920x1080. The weird thing is that this was not an issue until recently.

It's been about two weeks since I used my Laptop with an external display at home and my screen at work only goes up to 1920x1080, so I'm not sure when this started, but I reckon somewhere in the last two to three weeks. I guess it might have been some system update, but it was never an issue before.

I have tried adding a custom resolution using xrandr and changing display drivers by using Open Graphics Drivers. Neither solved my problem unfortunately. Any suggestions where to look further are greatly appreciated.

xrandr output:

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
1280x1440     59.91  
1680x1050     59.88  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      59.90  
1280x960      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
832x624       74.55  
800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       60.00    59.94  
640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  `
```

inxi -gXX output:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a16
       Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
       drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
       OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile
       version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.0-devel (git-3b2ad8b 2018-12-06 bionic-oibaf-ppa) (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
```